# Why am I getting multiple definition error when header included?

Tags: c++

I declare a `Algebra.h` file which holds the declaration of an `add()` function:

```
#ifndef Algebra_
#define Algebra_

namespace Algebra{

int add(int x, int y);

}
#endif
```

Then I implement `add()` as:

Algebra.cpp

```
#include "Algebra.h"

namespace Algebra{

int add(int x, int y){
  return x+y;
}

}
```

Then I have classes A and B, which include `Algebra.h`:

B.h

```
#ifndef B_
#define B_

#include "Algebra.h"
#include <iostream>

class B{
public:
  void func(int x, int y);
};

#endif
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

void B::func(int x, int y){
  int val =  Algebra::add(x,y);
  std::cout << "B : "<< val << std::endl;
}
```

A.h

```
#ifndef A_
#define A_

#include <iostream>

#include "Algebra.h"
#include "B.h"

class A{
public:
  void func(int x, int y);
};

#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"    

void A::func(int x, int y){
  int val =  Algebra::add(x,y);
  std::cout << "A : " << val << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "Algebra.h"

int main(){
  A a;
  B b;
  a.func(3,4);
  b.func(3,4);
  int val = Algebra::add(3,4);
  std::cout << "main : " << val << std::endl;
}
```

I tried compilation using

1. `g++ A.cpp B.cpp main.cpp -o bin`
2. `g++ A.cpp B.cpp Algebra.cpp main.cpp -o bin`

I get this error:

> /tmp/ccBXhev4.o: In function 'Algebra::add(int, int)':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of 'Algebra::add(int, int)'
>   /tmp/ccfaCF5H.o:A.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here collect2: error:
>   ld returned 1 exit status

I even tried inlining the `add()` function in `Algebra`, but still get the error. Also I don't want to make Algebra be a class.

Why am I getting a multiple definition error even though I am adding the Algebra header file, and it does not define but only declare?

Comment: `inline int add( int x, int y){ return x+y; }`

Comment: I tried that too but still get the error.

Comment: sorry, misread, thought the definition was in the header.

Comment: I had even tried with inlineing the definition in header and still get error.

Comment: 1) is missing Algebra.cpp 2) works for me

Comment: ok. I had to remove some of old *.h.gch files and now it works.

Comment: Note that you are not managing your headers correctly. `<iostream>` and `Algebra.h` should be moved from `A.h` and `B.h` to `A.cpp` and `B.cpp`, since they are not actually used in the `.h` files but only in the `.cpp` files. And `B.h` should be removed from `A.h` since `B` is not used by `A`. And `<iostream>` should be added to `main.cpp`. Use headers explicitly, only where they are actually needed, do not rely on headers being included implicitly, and do not include headers you do not need.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know I have thrown headers include all over the place. But was just curious. What is the reason behind you practice? Wouldn't compiler take care of this. Is it to make compiler run faster, by keeping it light weight by not including header every where?

Comment: @mato It is to avoid introducing dependencies where they do not belong and are not needed. And yes, that also helps to speed up compiling