# C++ Fixing multiple definition error when a header (a.hpp) is included in a header (b.hpp) corresponding source (b.cpp) and main.cpp

Tags: c++, header, namespaces

I have the following four files **a.hpp**, **b.hpp**, **b.cpp** and **main.cpp** in Ubuntu 16.04LTS that mimic my original files.

a.hpp

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <iostream>

namespace Utility{
    typedef struct _structure{
        int v;
        int w;
    }aStructure;

    void foo(){
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }

    void goo(){
        foo();
    }
}

#endif
```

b.hpp

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <iostream>

#include "a.hpp"

class bCls{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        void moo(Utility::aStructure s);
};

#endif
```

b.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"

void bCls::moo(Utility::aStructure s){
    std::cout << "moo" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"

int main(){

    Utility::aStructure s;
    bCls u;

    u.moo(s);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile using **g++ -std=c++11 b.cpp main.cpp** the following error message is thrown:

```
/tmp/ccwvPrRr.o: In function `Utility::foo()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Utility::foo()'
/tmp/ccCVJOoH.o:b.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccwvPrRr.o: In function `Utility::goo()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x23): multiple definition of `Utility::goo()'
/tmp/ccCVJOoH.o:b.cpp:(.text+0x23): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My search resulted in [Why am I getting multiple definition error when header included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008473/why-am-i-getting-multiple-definition-error-when-header-included). But one difference in my code is that **a.hpp** is required in each of **b.hpp**, **b.cpp** and **main.cpp**.

I am very curious to know what I am doing wrong and the best approach to code in this case and corresponding pitfalls.

Comment: Don't define your functions in the header. Put the definitions in a .cpp file.

Comment: You are not allowed to define functons in multiple translation units, with few exceptions (e.g. `inline` functions or templates). Because `include` copies and pastes content of the file into another file, you basically have two definitions of `Utilities::foo()` and linker is confused on which one it should use.

Comment: @drescherjm: Your advice solved my problem. Thank you.